# Customize subtitle position - JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart, subtitle

I want to know if it is possible to put a JFreeChart subtitle in the bottom of the chart, under the chart, and not under the Title.

What I want to do is illustrated on these images:

[image: actual]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmPJ8.jpg

and

[image: desired]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBfvL.jpg.

I just tried almost everything and cannot do this.

I am using subtitle insted of legend, because legend is presented with a red square, indicating the color of the series shown on the graphics.

Thanks in advance!

Joey

Answer (score 4):

In this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jfreechartdemo), the following [`TextTitle`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/title/TextTitle.html) appears to work.

```
chart.addSubtitle(new TextTitle(new Date().toString(),
    new Font("Dialog", Font.ITALIC, 14), Color.black,
    RectangleEdge.BOTTOM, HorizontalAlignment.CENTER,
    VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM, RectangleInsets.ZERO_INSETS));
```

[image]