# How to draw on charts?

Tags: jquery, jfreechart, highcharts

We are looking for a client side (something like Jquery) to draw on graphs .Something like [freestockcharts.com](http://www.freestockcharts.com) does it with Silverlight . We tried High Charts but ability to draw on the charts like lines,arch,circle  is not available Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highchart provides API to draw on the chart's canvas via Renderer class. Documentation is available here http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#renderer.

Answer (score 1):

[`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) supports a rich variety of [annotations](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/package-summary.html) (for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604211/jfreechart-draw-arc-on-chart/6620017#6620017)) and [titles](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/title/package-summary.html) (for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933187/customize-subtitle-position-jfreechart/6935174#6935174)). Deployment via [applet](/questions/tagged/applet) or [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) is possible; the latter is shown in the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).

Answer (score 0):

As for alternatives, have you seen [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

How about [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)? Haven't used it myself, but have heard good things.