# JFree chart selective point thickness

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using jfree chart for graphically displaying metrics.Now I am working on a solution which randomizes graph elements in an XY line chart so that the graph looks smoother.The problem is I dont want the random elements to get the same thickness as the real values,in fact I dont wan't any thickness associated with them.Is there a way to selectively specify point thickness.I am currently using  XYLineAndShapeRenderer to render the point thickness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override [`getItemShapeVisible()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html#getItemShapeVisible%28int,%20int%29) and arrange for it to return `false` for the spurious points. You can store the extra information required for the decision in your data model using an implementation of `XYZDataset`.

As an alternative, consider [smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing) the data before rendering it. Such filters typically result in *fewer* points, which  simplifies rendering.

In either case, avoid confusing or misleading changes to the data. A [`TextTitle`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/title/TextTitle.html), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6935174/230513), may clarify the result.

Addendum: `getItemShapeVisible()` tells *you* what `series` and `item` is under consideration. The default implementation simply asks `getSeriesShapesVisible()`. Here's an outline:

```
private static class MyRenderer extends XYLineAndShapeRenderer {

    @Override
    public boolean getItemShapeVisible(int series, int item) {
        System.out.println(series + ":" + item);
        if (item % 2 == 0) return false;
        else return super.getItemShapeVisible(series, item);
    }
}
```

Addendum: Here's how you might install it:

```
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
MyRenderer renderer = new MyRenderer();
plot.setRenderer(renderer);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,will try it.But is the index of a data series API specific,or is it just the index.How should I be implementing that.

Comment: I've updated the example to skip every other `Shape`, irrespective of series.

Comment: Thanks for your implementation example.I achieved it.Thanks much for your help.