# Marking points on a JFreeChart TimeSeries Chart

Tags: java, jfreechart, point

I have a JFreeChart TimeSeries chart that has 2 data item.
I need to mark points in it.
For example I need it show at a specific time what is the line's value (while there is not actually any value and JFreeChart created line).
Example:

```
TimeSeries t=new TimeSeries("Test",Second.class);
Dataset.addSeries(t);

Calendar C=Calendar.getInstance();
t.add(new Second(C.getTime()), 100);

C.setTimeInMillis(C.setTimeInMillis+10*60*60*1000);
t.add(new Second(C.getTime()),200);


// Now I want Something like this psudo code
C.setTimeInMillis(C.setTimeInMillis-5*60*60*1000);
t.mark(new Second(C.getTime()));
```

How Can I mark points on a series by their domain value (So the range value should be calculated automatically)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One convenient way to show interpolated values is to enable the axis trace feature, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513).

```
chartPanel.setHorizontalAxisTrace(true);
chartPanel.setVerticalAxisTrace(true);
```

Addendum: An alternative is to add the [interpolated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) values to the data set and suppress the display of their `Shape`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8635956/230513). The (unmarked) value will then be available to a tool tip generator, label generator, chart mouse listener, etc.

Comment: Hi Thanks but this only helps be to find value on the axis itself while I need exact value in some (exactly 3) point in the between two points.

Comment: You'll have to do your own [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) to translate _view_ to _model_ coordinates; the `drawXxxAxisTrace()` methods show how to get the _view_ bounds.