# JFreechart series movement with fixed x-axis

Tags: java, arduino, jfreechart

First question here. I'm doing an Arduino serial port plotter with Java and JFreeChart. Everything's working fine with the DynamicTimeSeries dataset, as I'm able to plot data nice and softly.

What I need to do  now is this: given an established period of time (let's say 60 seconds) I want to plot the DynamicTimeSeries dataset on the chart for that period without moving the axis; I mean, like drawing a line for 60 seconds on the fixed chart.

Is there any way to do this? Every example I've watched shows the x-axis (time axis) start running along with the series.

If I'm not clear enough please let me know.

Any help will be deeply appreciated!

Thanks!

PS: my code is based on this: [Using JFreeChart to display recent changes in a time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series#5048863), and this: [JFreeChart: DynamicTimeSeries with period of n milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856979/jfreechart-dynamictimeseries-with-period-of-n-milliseconds)

Comment: Assuming you start at zero, where does the data for the 60th second go? Back at zero? See also [*Real time graph plotting starting time*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31932309/230513), cited in your first reference, and be sure you're doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513).

Comment: The plot stops at 60 secs, until I press a reset button. I'll check your suggestions and see what happens. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `60` second chart, I'd expect domain indexes in the range `0..59`. Depending on your requirements,

- You can put the next value at index `0`, *or*
- You can  invoke `advanceTime()` and put the next value at index `59`.

Also consider invoking `setDateFormatOverride()` on the domain axis, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27230331/230513). See also [*Real time graph plotting starting time*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31902373/230513) and this answer about [*Using* `SwingWorker` *with* `JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513).